# CloudWatch metrics graph with condition on date of metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to access the date of the metric from a math expression in a custom CloudWatch graph, to be used in a `IF(...)` condition?

Background: I've made a custom CloudWatch graph showing the cost of a lambda, by calculating it from two standard metrics for `invocations` and `duration`. The expression uses the pricing formula published by AWS, such as `duration/1000*0.0000166667*0.50 + invocations*0.000002`, to give the cost in $ per the summed duration and invocations over a period.

However, this formula depends on the memory allocated to the function, which in this example is 512 MB ("0.50" factor in the expression). On a given date, some functions were reconfigured to get more RAM, and I want to reflect this in the graphs by doing something like `(if date > 2021-11-27 then 1.0 else 0.5)` to get the multiplying factor for the cost calculation.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - check our the [metric math docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#metric-math-syntax). You can use `EPOCH`, which is the unix timestamp in seconds. There are also `YEAR, MONTH, DATE, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE`, but they're not that useful in this case.

```
duration/1000*0.0000166667 * IF(EPOCH(duration)>1637971200, 1.0, 0.5) + invocations*0.000002
```

1637971200 is the unix timestamp for 2021-11-27.

Comment: Thanks, didn't find EPOCH. However, this produces the following error: `Error in expression cost [Unsupported operand type(s) for >: '[Function, Scalar]']`

Comment: Oof, that was an error on my part. You have to pass a metric to the function, edited the answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. And silly me for not finding that error (and for missing this to begin with, for some reason I find the CW graph spec a bit hard to follow).

Comment: FWIW, I ended up creating separate metrics like this:
`foo_dur` (sum of duration over period)
`foo_inv`(sum of invocations over period)
`foo_ram: IF(EPOCH(foo_dur) > 1637921266, 1.0, 0.5)`
`foo_cost: foo_dur/1000*0.0000166667 * foo_ram + foo_inv*0.000002`

It would be kind of nice if there were built-in cost metrics from the start, as this approach depends on up-to-date pricing info as well as region, but it works...

Comment: If this is something you expect to rely on in the long-term, I would start writing metrics that contain the price and RAM, so you would always have the needed historical data.